# How can i monitor a PHP file execution?

Tags: php, linux

Is there any way to monitor a php file execution from linux like mytop for mysql?
I mean that if i run an index.php, the command will show all steps of the file (requires, class call and so on) with execution time for every step?

Answer (score 1):

Closest to that can be combination of XDebug and QCachegrind [link](https://www.seidengroup.com/profiling-tools-for-php-qcachegrind-download/).

Comment: Thanks, i was trying only xDebug but with qcachegrind that is perfect.